# Query user details using employee ID

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-server, object-model

Is there a way to fetch user details from user profile service using employee ID?

Comment: What is the employee ID mapped to in this case?

Comment: we have created a custom property "EmployeeID" in user profile. So for each user a unique "EmployeeID" exists.

Comment: OK, well since there is no build in way to get the user by a custom property, you would have to iterate the collection of all users. Or you could try a search based approach for finding the corresponding LoginName for a EmployeeID

Comment: OK, Thanks Robert, will try the suggested approach.

Comment: Using JSOM? or CSOM? object-model means all of JSOM, CSOM and SSOM :)